# How could I effectively convert google-closure javascript to modern ES6?

Tags: webpack, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, transpiler

I have a code base that uses the google-closure style modules `goog.provide` and classes, etc.

I want to modernize this code base but it's roughly 15k lines of code and I was hoping a tool could help me.

These tools are broken, I tried many things to get them to work but they just wont. It's a lost cause.
https://github.com/angular/clutz
https://github.com/DreierF/closure-es6-converter

I think If I had a tool to update the closure classes and modules to the ES6 variants, I could do everything else by hand.

This tool works to update to a modern ES6 class syntax, but notably doesn't update the closure modules.
https://github.com/lebab/lebab

Would this tool allow me to convert closure modules to es6 modules? Or does it only produce a minified output.
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/closure-webpack-plugin/#usage-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 documents you should read about this:

[ES6 modules and Closure interop](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/ES6-modules-and-Closure-interop)

and

[Migrating from goog.modules to ES6 modules](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Migrating-from-goog.modules-to-ES6-modules)

Some highlights from each:

> ES6 modules can use goog.require like goog.modules to reference Closure files:
>
> ```
> const math = goog.require('goog.math');
> export const MY_CONSTANT = math.sum(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21);
> ```

---

> The Closure Library has the function `goog.declareModuleId(/** string */ id)`, which, when called in an ES6 module, associates the ES6 module with a goog.module-like id (e.g. something that can be `goog.require'd`, `goog.module.getd`, `goog.forwardDeclared`, and `goog.requireTyped`, and does not create any global symbols). goog.requires for these symbols will return the entire module object, as if bound by import * as.
>
> ```
> goog.declareModuleId('example.es6');
> export const MY_CONSTANT = 'Hello!';
> ```

And

> Closure module default exports
> Closure modules can have a "default" export via exports = value;. When using this syntax the module's exports become the default export. This is frequently used with modules that export a single class.
>
> ```
> goog.module('my.Class');
> class Class {}
> // Default export. goog.require for this module returns this class.
> exports = Class;
> ```

---

> What about migrating Closure modules that call declareLegacyNamespace?
> goog.module.declareLegacyNamespace is not supported in ES6 modules. It breaks a fundamental principle of modules: that modules do not create global values. Its purpose was to allow migration from goog.provide to Closure modules. We do not support it when moving to ES6 modules.
>
> It is recommended you migrate all goog.provided files that are relying on the declareLegacyNamespace call to Closure or ES6 modules first, or at the very least have them call goog.module.get in a goog.scope to get references to modules. If this is not possible and migration of the Closure module is still desired, you'll need to follow similar steps to migrating a Closure module with default exports, except your *_shim.js file will call declareLegacyNamespace. You will only be able to delete this file once all the goog.provide files have migrated.

Comment: I tried using const math = goog.require('goog.math'); in a simple test file, but math ends up being assigned null. Can you give a more complete example? The links are helpful, but also don't give this level of detail.